# How to access a list created in a stateful widget in one file to stateless widget in another file?

Tags: list, flutter

I have a stateful widget where there is a list like this,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todoapp/widgets/tasks_tile.dart';
import 'package:todoapp/models/Tasks.dart';

class TasksList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TasksListState createState() => _TasksListState();
}

class _TasksListState extends State<TasksList> {
  List<Task> task = [
    Task(
      taskTitle: "Buy Bread",
    ),
    Task(
      taskTitle: "Buy Cream",
    ),
    Task(
      taskTitle: "Buy Beer",
    )
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: task.length,
      itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return TaskTile(isChecked: task[index].isDone,
        taskText: task[index].taskTitle,
        callBackCheckBox: (bool checkBoxState){
          setState(() {
            task[index].toogleDone();
          });
        });
    });
  }
}
```

How do I access this list in stateless widget in another dart file?  I am new to flutter. And please explain the concept behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Aman Chaudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11418520/aman-chaudhary) to access `task` list it's done by passing all needed values in `Stateless` widget contructor in another dart file.

Here you can see that your `ListView.builder` is returning the `stateless` widget with all required parameters:

```
return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: task.length,
      itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return TaskTile(isChecked: task[index].isDone,
        taskText: task[index].taskTitle,
        callBackCheckBox: (bool checkBoxState){
          setState(() {
            task[index].toogleDone();
          });
        });
    });
```

This means whenever the `callBackCheckBox` is handled the `stateful` widget is refreshed and the `ListView.builder` updates his children with all `task` list updates.